# Setting bg color of component in Android always results in primary dark color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

I'm trying to change the background color of a custom list view item. Basically it's just a `LinearLayout` with 3 children. I'm setting the `android:background` property to `#FFFFFF`, thus I expect the resulting background color to be white.

The strange thing is that this always results in the bg color to be the `primaryDark` color. I'm using the `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` theme, thus the color is dark grey.

When I set the background color to `#FEFEFE` it works as expected. I'm only experiencing this behavior on my Android 4.1.2 device (Android 6 devices works as expected).

Does anybody know why this is happening?

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/faultCodeItemHeader"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="#FEFEFE"
  android:layout_margin="0dp"
  android:paddingTop="8dp"
  android:paddingBottom="8dp"
  android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/faultCodeItemHex"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".15"
    android:textColor="#FEFEFE"
    android:background="@drawable/faultcodes_hex"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/faultCodeItemTitle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".75"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:textColor="#030303" />
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/faultCodeItemCollapsed"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".10"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_down"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:padding="10dip" />
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/faultCodeItemExpanded"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".10"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_up"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:padding="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```